# What can be appended to a GitHub Repo URL?

Tags: github, repository

I know that if we append /stargazers to a github repo url, we get a list of stargazers. So I was wondering: what else can be added?

Looking for a comprehensive list. Tried googling but no luck. I thought saving this on SO would be helpful to others as well.